# Node.js access .env variables using their string names

Tags: node.js

I have an app that has a bunch of strings stored in variables. Each of these variables, has a corresponding .env variable that starts with that name. IE const BIRD and a .env variable named BIRD_AMOUNT.

How can I programmatically access the correct variblae using something like process.env + string variable?

Comment: Do you use [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) to parse the .env file?

Comment: yes, usually I access using process.env.MY_VARIABLE_X. Now I want to access it like this process.env.STRING_CONSTANT + _otherpartofvariable

Comment: `dotenv.config()` returns an object, `parsed`, where you can access both keys and values. Check this one out.

Comment: Trying that out thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access them as follows:

```
process.env[<string name>]
```

For example

```
const envVarRootName = 'BIRD_';
const otherVarNames = ['AMOUNT', 'COUNT', ...]
otherVarNames.forEach((name) => console.log(process.env[envVarRootName + name]));
```